# imageview position setting like this image

Tags: android, layout, position, imageview

I like to setting Imageview like this.

(http://wemakeucc.com/4.jpg) <-Check image please

I only use imageview like this until now.

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/a_01_b"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:src="@drawable/a_01_i" />
```

so I want to know code that can setting imageview like that image.

what should i do?

Comment: You can set top and left values inside the xml, in dp

Comment: so.. what should i do for set top and left values inside the xml..?

Comment: please explain with code..
I can't understand because I'm beginner

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code as per your requirement :

xml file: and screenshots

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/android" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="120dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/android" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

now just set the padding as per ur need...

Answer (score 2):

See the following xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_marginRight="40dip"
       android:layout_marginTop="60dip" // give dip value according to where you want to place first image view from top
       android:background="@color/black" // set image according to you
       android:id="@+id/imageviewone" />

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
       android:layout_marginTop="60dip" // give dip value what you have given to first edit text
       android:background="@color/black" // set image according to you
       android:layout_below="@+id/imageviewone"
       android:id="@+id/imageviewtwo" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

let me know if this helps you

Answer (score -1):

The answer you're looking for is in [`LayoutParams`][1].

to answer your question:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_imageView);
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams absParams = 
    (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams)iv.getLayoutParams();
absParams.x = myX;
absParams.y = myY;
iv.setLayoutParams(absParams);
```

explanation: you are setting some kind of anchor-point (x/y( for your ImageView